# Generate pairwise movement data from sequence

Tags: r

I have a sequence which looks like this

```
  SEQENCE
1       A
2       B
3       B
4       C
5       A
```

Now from this sequence, I want to get the matrix like this where i the row and jth column element denotes how many times movement occurred from ith row node to jth column node

```
  A B C
A 0 1 0
B 0 1 1
C 1 0 0
```

How Can I get this in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Use `table` like this:

```
s <- DF[, 1]
table(tail(s, -1), head(s, -1))
```

giving:

```
    A B C
  A 0 0 1
  B 1 1 0
  C 0 1 0
```

**2)** or like this. Since `embed` does not work with factors we convert the factor to character,

```
s <- as.character(DF[, 1])
do.call(table, data.frame(embed(s, 2)))
```

giving:

```
   X2
X1  A B C
  A 0 0 1
  B 1 1 0
  C 0 1 0
```

**3)** `xtabs` also works:

```
s <- as.character(DF[, 1])
xtabs(data = data.frame(embed(s, 2)))
```

giving:

```
   X2
X1  A B C
  A 0 0 1
  B 1 1 0
  C 0 1 0
```

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "  SEQENCE
1       A
2       B
3       B
4       C
5       A"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```